I forgot the dry milk in my bread maker recipe
I forgot the dry milk in my 2 lb loaf; it completed the first kneed cycle, do I start over?

There is a lot of context missing from your question, which makes it quite hard to answer.  Including your recipe would likely help---I'm not very familiar with the use of dry milk in a bread recipe, so it would be helpful to know where you are starting from.  It would also help to know precisely what you have done---are you using a bread maker (having finished a "knead cycle" seems to imply this, but one cannot be sure)?

Since self-answering is encouraged at stack exchange sites (take the [tour]) please take some pictures of your loaf and post an answer with your resulting bread, as well as [edit]ing your question to include the recipe.

@XanderHenderson it's fairly common in bread machine recipe books (from a few brands).

Neither panic nor start over.
It will be different, but it will be bread.
Milk is entirely optional in making bread. The differences between bread made with it and without it are relatively small, on the whole. The crust may brown somewhat less due to not having the lactose, and the crumb may be somewhat coarser. But it will be fairly similar to your normal result.
